# Log if process is active or not

Tags: server, remote, automation, html

I'm trying to make a web page which shows if a process is active or not, but how can I automate the process check and write that to a .txt or .html file so I can show it on my site?

Comment: Good solution will be `monit`. it's easy for installation and process/service monitoring. Also already have html page with service status. Only left to you is to integrate monit html output in your page

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `pgrep` to search for processes with a specific name.

As an example, I can see if the music player Rhythmbox is running by typing this:

```
$ pgrep rhythmbox
827
```

If any numbers are printed (and the exit status is 0), this means it found a matching process. Otherwise the output will be empty and you get a non-zero exit status.

Now we can simply run this over and over in an infinite loop. To save resources, we wait a second between each iteration. Depending if a matching process is found or not, this little script below will then either write `yes` or `no` to a file `status.txt`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 1 ; do 
    if pgrep rhythmbox &>/dev/null ; then 
        echo "yes" > status.txt
    else 
        echo "no" > status.txt
    fi
done
```

You could also do anything more useful inside the loop, like e.g. switching symlinks between two pre-made html documents. Assume we have `running.html` and `stopped.html` and want to have the correct one of those linked as `status.html`, which then could be served by your web server. It could look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 1 ; do 
    if pgrep rhythmbox &>/dev/null ; then 
        ln -s running.html status.html
    else 
        ln -s stopped.html status.html
    fi
done
```

I haven't tested how a web server might react on this link switching though, it could also be possible that it caches stuff and changes won't be live immediately, no idea. You've got to try it out.

Comment: I've tried this, the exact code I used is this

`#!/bin/bash
while sleep 1 ; do 
    if pgrep java &>/dev/null ; then 
        echo "<html><title>yes</title><body>yes</body>" > /var/www/html/stat.html
    else 
        echo "<html><title>no</title><body>no</body>" > /var/www/html/stat.html
    fi
done `
But it said that java was active and when I did `killall java`It didn't update and said that Java wasn't active

Comment: You might have to tailor your `pgrep` command to match what you want. If you just run `pgrep -a java`, check if that matches what you need correctly. (-a just also shows the command line, not only the process id in the output). You might also want to try adding `-f` to match against the full command line, not just the process name, like `pgrep -fa java`.

Comment: I found what I did wrong, it wasn't `java` and then the procces but just the procces